# Flutter access model attribute using dynamic key

Tags: object, dart, flutter, setter, getter

For example in PHP,

```
$key1 = 'name'; 
$key2 = 'mobile';

$person = new Person();
$person->{$key1} = 'Ahmad';
$person->{$mobile} = '60148220678';
```

How can I achieve in Flutter (Dart language)? I have tried

```dart
var key1 = 'name';
Person _person = new Person();

_person.{key1} = 'Ahmad';
```

But it shows an error instead

Comment: I also tried to do the same, but I don't think is possible. You can try with the `Map Class` https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/Map-class.html  to get something similar.

Comment: `class Point {
  num x;
  num y;
}

void main() {
  var point = Point();
  point.x = 4; // Use the setter method for x.
  assert(point.x == 4); // Use the getter method for x.
  assert(point.y == null); // Values default to null.
  print(point.x);
}` [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#classes)